# Table display to flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a client project that contains a lot of table elements. I am wondering if it is ok to convert all the table cells and rows to: `display: flex`?

Should I go through the additional work of rewriting all the table elements to divs and change the display flex there?

Comment: This is where JavaScript can be your best friend. Do you have a 1000 nodes that need changing? No problem with `node.style.display = 'flex'` in a loop. Keep in mind that this style should be applied to elements that have children. To place the properties on `td`s with little to no children is a waste of time. Post a [mcve] and I'll show you.

Comment: If your question is, "should I keep the <table> tags or should I change them to <div>s when I change the `display` property", then this question is off topic: there is no correct answer, only heated discussion.

Comment: My take is that if it's actually a table, then by all means keep the <table> tags. If it is not really a table, but just a layout  mechanism, then it should not have been a <table> to begin with. No matter the `display` property.

Comment: if its suppose to be very responsive, then yes.

Comment: As @MrLister says, changing a table layout when the data is tabular, just because it's more modern, it's pointless. But there is not a general answer to this without seeing what has been used the table for. I believe this is an opinion based question.